# React - Material-UI version 6, renderInput Property not available in DesktopDatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As mentioned in the header,
using React with the Material UI Version.6 Llibrary,

I want to customize the rendered Input.

In Version.5 there is the property "inputProp" of DateTimePicker,
in Version.6 it is not available anymore and i cannot find any renaming or anything about it in the Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `slots` and `slotProps`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wafgu1?file=src%2FMobileDatePickerWithCalendarIcon.js

Please check this example.